# runtime error '-2147217871(80040e31)' query timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, excel, macros

This is my code:

```
strglsql = "Select * from stg_glactualdata a inner join ( select item1.item_master_code from stg_dim_item item1 ,stg_dim_item item2 where item1.dim02_value = item2.dim02_value And item1.dim03_value = item2.dim03_value And item1.dim12_value = item2.dim12_value) b on a.Item_SKUCode = b.item_master_code "
varglactual.ActiveConnection = VarVmConnection
varglactual.Open strglsql
```

When executing I get:

> runtime error '-2147217871(80040e31)' query timeout expired

What possibly could be a problem?

Comment: How are we suppose to help you with that?

Comment: I am sorry but the join inside the subquery does not make sense:    

select item1.item_master_code    
from  stg_dim_item item1, stg_dim_item item2    
where item1.dim02_value = item2.dim02_value    
 And item1.dim03_value = item2.dim03_value    
 And item1.dim12_value = item2.dim12_value

Comment: its getting executed correctly in sql server. I am getting query timeout error while executing it in excel macros. any help will be appreciated.          thanks in advance

Comment: Set values to properties like ConnectionTimeOut, CommandTimeOut. Set them to  0. Still I think the join inside the subquery is incorrect.

Comment: join is working fine..that's a self join.

Comment: It WILL work, but I think there's no need to: the joining fields dim02_value, dim03_value and dim12_value is joining itself.

Comment: i have changed the connection timeout to 0 , still not working...                         Set VarVmConnection = New ADODB.Connection
'VarVmConnection.Close
 With VarVmConnection
    .Provider = "SQLNCLI11"
    .ConnectionString = "Server=" & VarServer & ";Database=VM;UID=vmuser;PWD=vmu;Connect Timeout= 0"
'    MsgBox VarVmConnection.ConnectionString
.Open
 End With

Comment: Try the VarVmConnection.CommandTimeout. And I assume that you are using ADODB.Command too, there's a Timeout property there as well.

Comment: thank you so much..its working fine now :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Still I'd say that your self-join is not making sense.The resultset will be the same if you use this but this is more efficient: select item1.item_master_code from stg_dim_item item1 group by item1.item_master_code

Comment: actually i had to get those items having same dim02_value,dim03_value and dim12_value..that is why i used self join.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this from open cmd with Administrator and run these commands in the following order

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
This optional
Sfc /scannow
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-ES/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors#description-of-the-common-corruption-errors) can help.